# What happens to your files on Windows after installing ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, files

First of all I would like to say that I am new to ubuntu and i couldn't find anything about this on the web.

I'm planning on installing Ubuntu 12.10 on my pc ( I want to erase windows of my pc )but I was wondering if I will be able to keep my files after installing Ubuntu or will everything be erased by installing the ubuntu OS. Of course I will be backing-up all my files in DropBox. But is there a way that I wont need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you do during the partitioning part of the installation.

1. You can install Ubuntu along side Windows (`dual boot`) on `unallocated` space on your sytsem (you might need to create that space with something like Partition Magic). If done correctly this will result in the Windows files staying on your system where you can switch between Windows and Ubuntu.
2. You can erase all other operating systems and have Ubuntu as the only OS. This will destroy all software on the partitions you choose to use for Ubuntu. Let's say you have a D: disc that is a separate partition. If you do not format this you will end up with a disc inside Ubuntu that you can mount and access those files. Depending on what they are (.doc(x)/.txt) there will be programs they can open and save those (libreoffice, gedit).

Just make a backup, like you intend to, and all should be fine. Have fun!

Comment: Thanxxxx for your answer